# How to show indication at the bottom of spinner list in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I want to show indication at the bottom of spinner list. Suppose i have 10 values in array list when i click on the spinner then it shows first 5 rest shown after scroll the list. I want to show indication at bottom to scroll the list for more values.

Comment: i guess a custom dialog which simulates the spinner

Comment: i have use custom dialog for this but i dont know how to find the last item index shows in the list? Have you know how to find the last item position.

Comment: you could use make a relativeView with a ScrollView and a button(or View) that's always at the bottom, but that woudn't work, what about enabling to always show the scrollbar could that be enough to make the user understand?

Comment: I dont want to show the button at bottom always. Yes i can do by enabling the scrollbar but its not my requirement.